# error on imagemagick for TileView android

Tags: android, image

So I'm working with [TileView](https://github.com/moagrius/TileView) and I'm with some troubles.

When I follow this tutorial for [Creating Tiles](https://github.com/moagrius/TileView/wiki/Creating-Tiles) with this:

```
   `   @echo off

 echo should already have original image in folder, as well as folders named 
 tiles and samples
 set basename=my_image_base_name
 set filename=my-image.jpg
 set extension=jpg

 set imagemagick=C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\image.jpg
 set /a tilesize=256
 set /a samplesize=500

 set tilesfolder=tiles
 set samplesfolder=samples

 echo create tile folders
 mkdir %tilesfolder%\%basename%
 mkdir %tilesfolder%\%basename%\1000
 mkdir %tilesfolder%\%basename%\500
 mkdir %tilesfolder%\%basename%\250
 mkdir %tilesfolder%\%basename%\125

 echo create half-sized versions for tiling (will be discarded later)
 %imagemagick% %filename% -resize 50%%  %basename%-500.%extension%
 %imagemagick% %filename% -resize 25%%  %basename%-250.%extension%
 %imagemagick% %filename% -resize 12.5%%  %basename%-125.%extension%
 echo create sample
 %imagemagick% %filename% -thumbnail %samplesize%x%samplesize%  
 ./%samplesfolder%/%filename%

 echo create tiles
 %imagemagick% %filename% -crop %tilesize%x%tilesize% -set filename:tile "%%
[fx:page.x/%tilesize%]_%%[fx:page.y/%tilesize%]" +repage +adjoin 
 "./%tilesfolder%/%basename%/1000/%%[filename:tile].%extension%"
 %imagemagick% %basename%-500.%extension% -crop %tilesize%x%tilesize% -set 
filename:tile "%%[fx:page.x/%tilesize%]_%%[fx:page.y/%tilesize%]" +repage 
+adjoin "./%tilesfolder%/%basename%/500/%%[filename:tile].%extension%"
%imagemagick% %basename%-250.%extension% -crop %tilesize%x%tilesize% -set 
filename:tile "%%[fx:page.x/%tilesize%]_%%[fx:page.y/%tilesize%]" +repage 
+adjoin "./%tilesfolder%/%basename%/250/%%[filename:tile].%extension%"
%imagemagick% %basename%-125.%extension% -crop %tilesize%x%tilesize% -set 
filename:tile "%%[fx:page.x/%tilesize%]_%%[fx:page.y/%tilesize%]" +repage 
+adjoin "./%tilesfolder%/%basename%/125/%%[filename:tile].%extension%"

 echo cleanup
del %tilesfolder%\%basename%-500.%extension%
del %tilesfolder%\%basename%-250.%extension%
del %tilesfolder%\%basename%-125.%extension%

echo DONE
 pause`
```

And after this, its creating empty folders.
I cant find anything on Google and I need help, please

Answer (score 0):

> set imagemagick=C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\image.jpg

This is setting a call to imagemagick but is really defining it to be an image and not the ImageMagick convert or magick commands.

set it to the path to ImageMagick convert or magick depending upon whether you are using IM 6 or IM 7

Comment: Ok, I changed this variable to magick.exe path but still the same

Comment: Do you ever use TileView?

Comment: I have never used TileView. See the response on the ImageMagick Discourse server that I posted about your conversion to Unix shell script. See http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=32085&start=15#p146613